# jQuery Json Filter and Append to HTML Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I am trying to filter out this JSON object based on the country code present in the object as.

http://jsfiddle.net/870ctvnm

There is a primary selector which a user uses to select the Currency. After which I want to filter out all the available payment options based on the country code and then append the filtered object to the payment selector.

I tried using `$.grep` and `$.filter` both failed. Would be great if someone could help out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, data.js contains that variable, var payments.

```
<label>Currency</label>
<select class="form-control" onchange="currency_update(this);">
  <option>---</option>  <option value="ADP">ADP</option>  <option value="AED">AED</option>  <option value="AFA">AFA</option>  <option value="ALL">ALL</option>  <option value="ANG">ANG</option>  <option value="AOK">AOK</option>  <option value="ARS">ARS</option>  <option value="AUD">AUD</option>  <option value="AWG">AWG</option>  <option value="BBD">BBD</option>  <option value="BDT">BDT</option>  <option value="BGN">BGN</option>  <option value="BHD">BHD</option>  <option value="BIF">BIF</option>  <option value="BMD">BMD</option>  <option value="BND">BND</option>  <option value="BOB">BOB</option>  <option value="BRL">BRL</option>  <option value="BSD">BSD</option>  <option value="BTN">BTN</option>  <option value="BUK">BUK</option>  <option value="BWP">BWP</option>  <option value="BZD">BZD</option>  <option value="CAD">CAD</option>  <option value="CHF">CHF</option>  <option value="CLF">CLF</option>  <option value="CLP">CLP</option>  <option value="CNY">CNY</option>  <option value="COP">COP</option>  <option value="CRC">CRC</option>  <option value="CZK">CZK</option>  <option value="CUP">CUP</option>  <option value="CVE">CVE</option>  <option value="CYP">CYP</option>  <option value="DKK">DKK</option>  <option value="DOP">DOP</option>  <option value="DZD">DZD</option>  <option value="ECS">ECS</option>  <option value="EGP">EGP</option>  <option value="EEK">EEK</option>  <option value="ETB">ETB</option>  <option value="EUR">EUR</option>  <option value="FJD">FJD</option>  <option value="FKP">FKP</option>  <option value="GBP">GBP</option>  <option value="GHC">GHC</option>  <option value="GIP">GIP</option>  <option value="GMD">GMD</option>  <option value="GNF">GNF</option>  <option value="GTQ">GTQ</option>  <option value="GWP">GWP</option>  <option value="GYD">GYD</option>  <option value="HKD">HKD</option>  <option value="HNL">HNL</option>  <option value="HTG">HTG</option>  <option value="HUF">HUF</option>  <option value="IDR">IDR</option>  <option value="IEP">IEP</option>  <option value="ILS">ILS</option>  <option value="INR">INR</option>  <option value="IQD">IQD</option>  <option value="IRR">IRR</option>  <option value="JMD">JMD</option>  <option value="JOD">JOD</option>  <option value="JPY">JPY</option>  <option value="KES">KES</option>  <option value="KHR">KHR</option>  <option value="KMF">KMF</option>  <option value="KPW">KPW</option>  <option value="KRW">KRW</option>  <option value="KWD">KWD</option>  <option value="KYD">KYD</option>  <option value="LAK">LAK</option>  <option value="LBP">LBP</option>  <option value="LKR">LKR</option>  <option value="LRD">LRD</option>  <option value="LSL">LSL</option>  <option value="LYD">LYD</option>  <option value="MAD">MAD</option>  <option value="MGF">MGF</option>  <option value="MNT">MNT</option>  <option value="MOP">MOP</option>  <option value="MRO">MRO</option>  <option value="MTL">MTL</option>  <option value="MUR">MUR</option>  <option value="MVR">MVR</option>  <option value="MWK">MWK</option>  <option value="MXP">MXP</option>  <option value="MYR">MYR</option>  <option value="MZM">MZM</option>  <option value="NAD">NAD</option>  <option value="NGN">NGN</option>  <option value="NIO">NIO</option>  <option value="NOK">NOK</option>  <option value="NPR">NPR</option>  <option value="NZD">NZD</option>  <option value="OMR">OMR</option>  <option value="PAB">PAB</option>  <option value="PEN">PEN</option>  <option value="PGK">PGK</option>  <option value="PHP">PHP</option>  <option value="PKR">PKR</option>  <option value="PLN">PLN</option>  <option value="PYG">PYG</option>  <option value="QAR">QAR</option>  <option value="RON">RON</option>  <option value="RWF">RWF</option>  <option value="SAR">SAR</option>  <option value="SBD">SBD</option>  <option value="SCR">SCR</option>  <option value="SDP">SDP</option>  <option value="SEK">SEK</option>  <option value="SGD">SGD</option>  <option value="SHP">SHP</option>  <option value="SLL">SLL</option>  <option value="SOS">SOS</option>  <option value="SRG">SRG</option>  <option value="STD">STD</option>  <option value="RUB">RUB</option>  <option value="SVC">SVC</option>  <option value="SYP">SYP</option>  <option value="SZL">SZL</option>  <option value="THB">THB</option>  <option value="TND">TND</option>  <option value="TOP">TOP</option>  <option value="TPE">TPE</option>  <option value="TRY">TRY</option>  <option value="TTD">TTD</option>  <option value="TWD">TWD</option>  <option value="TZS">TZS</option>  <option value="UGX">UGX</option>  <option value="USD">USD</option>  <option value="UYU">UYU</option>  <option value="VEF">VEF</option>  <option value="VND">VND</option>  <option value="VUV">VUV</option>  <option value="WST">WST</option>  <option value="XAF">XAF</option>  <option value="XAG">XAG</option>  <option value="XAU">XAU</option>  <option value="XCD">XCD</option>  <option value="XDR">XDR</option>  <option value="XOF">XOF</option>  <option value="XPD">XPD</option>  <option value="XPF">XPF</option>  <option value="XPT">XPT</option>  <option value="YDD">YDD</option>  <option value="YER">YER</option>  <option value="YUD">YUD</option>  <option value="ZAR">ZAR</option>  <option value="ZMK">ZMK</option>  <option value="ZRZ">ZRZ</option>  <option value="ZWD">ZWD</option>  <option value="SKK">SKK</option>  <option value="AMD">AMD</option>
</select>
<label>Payment Method</label>
<select id="methods"></select>

<script src="data.js"></script>
<script>
// notice: data.js contains var payments = [{ ... }];
function currency_update(elm) {
  var currency = elm.value;
  var i = 0;
  document.getElementById('methods').innerHTML = '';
  for(key in payments[0]) {
    var allowed_currencies = payments[0][key].currencies || [];
    if(allowed_currencies.indexOf(currency)) {
      addPayment(i, key);
    }
    i++
  }
}
function addPayment(i, key) {
  document.getElementById('methods').innerHTML += '<option value="' + payments[0][key].name + '">' + payments[0][key].name + '</option>';
}
</script>
```

I don't use that i, but it might be useful.